# Yii2 query for users in group

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-model

I had a DB that had a `user` table and a `group` table and the group table had a column `user_id` which made it simply to return a list of users in a group:

```
$users = User::find()
  ->where(['{{user}}.group_id' => $group_id])
  ->all();
```

Now the user_id column is gone and there is a third table `group_user` with `user_id` and `group_id` columns for the relationship.

I tried this:

```
$users = User::find()
  ->innerJoinWith('group_user)
  ->where(['{{group_user}}.group_id' => $group_id])
```

but received this error:

```
User has no relation named "group_user"
```

But I set the relationship in the User model:

```
public function getGroupUser() {
    return $this->hasOne(GroupUser::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

What am I missing? This is used in a [Humhub API](https://github.com/humhub/humhub).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would reprogram your `getGroupUser` (renaming it to `getGroups`) relation using `viaTable`:

```
public function getGroups() {
    return $this->hasMany(Group::className(), ['user_group.id_group' => 'group.id'])
        ->viaTable('user_group', ['user.id' => 'user_group.id_user']);
}
```

That would give you the Group(s) a User belongs to. But I think you are aiming to get the Users that belong to a given group, so similarly I would create a `getUsers` relation in your `Group` model:

```
public function getUsers() { 
      return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']) 
        ->viaTable('group_user', ['group_id' => 'id']);
```

}

Then:

```
$group = Group::findOne($id_group);
$users = $group->getUsers()->all();
```

Comment: `Getting unknown property: \\api\\models\\Group::group_user.group_id` on this function:  `public function getUsers() {
      return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['group_user.user_id' => 'user.id'])
          ->viaTable('group_user', ['group.id' => 'group_user.group_id']);
  }`

Comment: I had a typo, `=` instead of `=>`. I also updated tables and column names

Comment: No problem ... I caught the typos, including table and field names ;)

Comment: OK I got rid of that error by changing getUsers() to:  `public function getUsers() {
      return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['group_user.user_id' => 'user.id'])
          ->viaTable('group_user', ['group_user.group_id' => 'id']);
  }`   But now I get an error `Undefined index: user.id` on that function.

Comment: What is the primary key of your user table? it is not `user.id`?

Comment: Yes it is `user.id`

Comment: What if your replace `user.id` with `id`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139995/discussion-between-gmc-and-lilbiscuit).